Как загрузить фотографию в SunEditor на сервер используя onImageUploadBefore?
Мне необходимо загружать фотографии на сервер, я прописала функцию onImageUploadBefore. Все работает, фото загружается, отображается в эдиторе. Но в эдиторе теперь отображаются две фотографии, одна с путем с сервера, вторая  в формате base64.
Как сделать так чтобы фото в формате base64 не отображалось?


const TextSunEditor = ({
    onChange,
    value
}) => {

    async function handleImageUploadBefore(files, info, uploadHandler){
        console.log(files, info)

        const currentFile = files[0];

        const res = await FileUpload.upload(currentFile);

        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            const { url } = res.content;
            uploadHandler({
                result: [{ url }],
            });
            toast.success(res.message)
        } else {
            toast.error(res.message)
        }
    }

  return (
    <SunEditor 
        setOptions={{
          height: 400,
          buttonList: [
            ['undo', 'redo'],
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
            ['font', 'fontSize', 'formatBlock'],
            ['paragraphStyle', 'blockquote'],
            ['fontColor', 'hiliteColor', 'textStyle'],
            ['removeFormat'],
            '/',
            ['outdent', 'indent'],
            ['align', 'horizontalRule', 'list', 'lineHeight'],
            ['link', 'image', 'video'],
            ['fullScreen', 'showBlocks', 'codeView'],
            ['preview', 'print']
          ],
        }}
        onImageUploadBefore={handleImageUploadBefore}
        onChange={onChange}
        setContents={value}
      />
  )
}



